# Develop WPF on Window 7 (32 bit) VMware guest on Mac OS X (64 bit) host

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I installed Windows 7 (32 bit) on VMware running on Mac OS X 10.6 (64 bit).

I have VS 2010 on the Windows 7 guest. I developed a WPF C# .NET 4 application using this VS 2010. Will the application be a 32 bit or 64 bit application in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32bit. Its your windows machine that is executing the application, and that is 32bit.

.Net applications (and by inclusion WPF applications) are compiled into IL, which is actually converted to machine code by the framework.  By default, this IL code is set to be able to run on both CPU types and therefore if your end users are on 64bit machines with 64bit framework, they will get a 64bit application.  If 32bit with 32bit framework, they will get a 32bit application.

Comment: unfortunately editing a 64bit wpf application while debugging is not supported by vs2012 at this time

Answer (score 1):

32bits in this case. It depends on the platform Visual Studio installed on.